# How to iterate a list and check for match

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I have a object

```
public class QuestionDetails {

    private List<SubQuestion> subQuestions;
    private Long questionId;
}
```

and i declared SubQuestion as

```
public class SubQuestion{

    private List<SubQuestion> childQuestions;
    private Long questionId;

}
```

i am getting question id from user as "questionId" and QuestionDetails object from DB.

**Logic**

I want to compare the questionId from user with questionId in subQuestions list to get subQuestions object and if i didn't find any match then i wanna go to childQuestions in the same subQuestions object to see if childQuestions list has any match.How can i do that in java8?
Right now what i am doing is ,i am checking all sub questions first and if i didn't find any match  then i am looking into all child question. my code is below

```
Long questionId = dto.getQuestions().get(0).getQuestionId ();
     subQuestion= questionDetails.getSubQuestions().stream()
            .filter(sub -> (new Long(sub.getQuestionId()).equals(new Long(questionId))))
            .findAny() .orElse(questionDetailsDTO.getSubQuestions().stream()
                    .flatMap(sub -> sub.getChildQuestions().stream())
                    .filter(child -> (new Long(child.getQuestionId()).equals(newLong(questionId))))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(null));
```

Comment: Why would you do `new Long()`?

Comment: I am using new Long() so that i can use equals() method for comparison

Comment: What's wrong with primitive comparison?

Comment: i haven't tried yet

Comment: Is there just one level of child questions within a sub-question, or can those also have children of their own?

Comment: “i haven't tried yet”—So you *start* with an unnecessarily complex expression instead of a straight-forward one? It’s even weirder considering that the values *are* already of type `Long` before you use `new Long(…)`, which unboxes them to `long`, to box them to `Long` again. There is, by the way, a space missing at `newLong(questionId)`. Further, you didn’t ask a question.

Comment: @ Tim Moore ,only one level of  child questions within a sub-question

Comment: So your question is? Simplify this code or something else?

Comment: Simplify the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a simplified solution, you can use

```java
long questionId = dto.getQuestions().get(0).getQuestionId();
SubQuestion subQuestion = Stream.concat(
      questionDetails.getSubQuestions().stream(),
      questionDetails.getSubQuestions().stream()
          .flatMap(sub -> sub.getChildQuestions().stream())
    )
    .filter(sub -> sub.getQuestionId() == questionId)
    .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Since `findFirst()` respects the encounter order and streams are lazy, the second stream using `flatMap` will only be processed when the first stream did not encounter a match.

Using `long` for the type of `questionId` ensures that the `==` operator compares the value rather than object identities, regardless of whether `getQuestionId()` returns `Long` or `long`.